# Why does printing a list copied from a DataFrame also print the Name and dtype of every row?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm relatively new to Python, and super new to Pandas.  I'm trying to cross-reference two DataFrames; finding the people that meet a condition in DataFrame A, and creating a new DataFrame with their name plus their "value" from DataFrame B.  I've got the main logic working, but for some reason when I go to print the DataFrame I created that contains that person's name and value, it also prints data about the person's name and value like so:

```
 [277    Joe Smith
 Name: Name, dtype: object, 277    0.7
 Name: Value, dtype: float64], [207    Steve Smith
 Name: Name, dtype: object, 207    0.6
 Name: Value, dtype: float64]
```

To be honest, I'm not even sure what the 277 and 207 numbers represent.  What I'm expecting is something like:

```
 Joe Smith  0.7
 Steve Smith 0.6
```

The way I'm creating the DataFrame is:

```
for index, row in myplayers.iterrows():
    playerrow = allplayers['playerID'] == row['playerID']
    playerlist.append([allplayers.loc[playerrow,'Name'],allplayers.loc[playerrow,'Value']])
```

Where myplayers contains the playerID of all the players I'm interested in, and allplayers is the DataFrame containing the player names, IDs, and values.

At the end, I print with:

```
print(playerlist)
```

I've seen suggestions to do things like print(playerlist.to_string()) but the same things seems to happen.  Is it a problem with the way I'm adding items?  Or is there a better way to print a list like that?

Thanks!

Comment: `allplayers.loc[playerrow,'Name']` returns a Series object instead of scalar  value, 277 and 207 are indices of those matching rows.

Comment: Oh, how do I get just the value?

Comment: `allplayers.loc[playerrow,'Name'].iat[0]` probably, but I think you need [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) for what you want to do. Loop and filter like you are doing is going to slow.

Comment: Ah yup, that did it!  Thanks so much!  And yeah from the other comments it sounds like maybe there's a more efficient way to do it overall...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the copy and reindex() method:

```
playerDataFrame = dataFrame2.copy()
player_names = ['Joe Smith', 'Steve Smith']
playerDataFrame.reindex(player_names]
```

To print the contents of the dataframe, use the head() method:

```
playerDataFrame.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

> [...] is there a better way [...]

Why deal with lists and not just do

```
# Data Of Interest
doi = allplayers.set_index('playerID').loc[
    myplayers.playerID,
    ['Name', 'Value']
]
```

which displays as <sub>*with invented players ids*</sub>.

```
>>> doi
                 Name  Value
playerID                    
JS          Joe Smith  0.700
SS        Steve Smith  0.600
```

and finally you could call [`pandas.DataFrame.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) to retrieve something that really looks like what you want

```
>>> doi.to_dict('split')['data']
[['Joe Smith', 0.7], ['Steve Smith', 0.6]]
```

Comment: Any question @AdamL ?

Answer (score 0):

You already got your answer for a correct output below, but for your other question (why the additional info is getting ouput) -> iterrows() returns a SERIES for each row, because you iterate over DataFrame rows as (index, Series) pairs.

Comment: Ah ok, but I thought I was getting the row with playerrow, then finding the appropriate column using 'Name' and 'Value'.  I guess I'm still a little confused why that's still a series and not a value.